# How to add a separator when accessing two different fields from different tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```sql
DECLARE @test1 varchar = 'This is test 1';
DECLARE @test2 varchar = 'This is test 2';

SELECT 
        'Expected output' = isnull(@test1, '') + '. ' +  isnull(@test2, '')
```

Expected output should be "This is test 1. This is test 2". But if there is nothing in `@test1` then do not show the ". " separator.

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a recent version of SQL Server, just use `CONCAT_WS`:

```
DECLARE @test1 varchar(30) = 'This is test 1'; --Always define your length, precision and scale!
DECLARE @test2 varchar(30) = 'This is test 2'; --Always define your length, precision and scale!
/*
{'Literal String Alias' = Expression} is deprecated! Don't use it.
Don't, however, use literal strings for aliases at all, it is confusing.
Ideally, don't use object names/aliases that require delimit identification.
If you must use the T-SQL ([]) or ANSI (") delimit identifiers.
*/
SELECT CONCAT_WS('.',@test1, @test2) AS ExpectedResult;
```

If you're on an older version of SQL Server, prefix your separator at the start of each value and use `STUFF` to remove the first one:

```sql
DECLARE @test1 varchar(30) = 'This is test 1'; --Always define your length, precision and scale!
DECLARE @test2 varchar(30) = 'This is test 2'; --Always define your length, precision and scale!

SELECT STUFF(CONCAT('.' + @test1,'.' + @test2),1,1,'') AS ExpectedResult;
```

Comment: Thank you. Concat_ws is however not recognized as a built in function. I am using microsoft sql server management studio 2018

Comment: *"Concat_ws is however not recognized as a built in function"* which is why I stated if you're on  a *recent* version of SQL Server, @saafiyah , and then go on to provide a solution that works on older versions. There are 2 solutions there; the latter will work on the older version you are using. There is, however, no SSMS 2018; there is SSMS version 18, but that supports SQL Server 2008 - 2019 so doesn't tell me much about what version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: thanks guys I ended up using a STUFF function within a CASE and basically checking if '@test1' is null then setting it to empty and the same with @test2 to avoid the trailing '. ' when '@test1' is empty.

Answer (score 1):

> if there is nothing in @test1 then do not show the ". " separator.

Perhaps the simplest method is:

```
SELECT CONCAT(@test1 + '. ', @test2)
```

`CONCAT()` ignores `NULL` values, but `+` does not.  So if `@test1` is `NULL` then the first expression is `NULL` and gets ignored.

Comment: This will, however, have a trailing `'. '` on the value if `@test1` has a non-`NULL` value, and `@test2` is `NULL`.

Comment: @Larnu . . . I am aware of that.  However, that is not what the OP is asking.  I have quoted the relevant part of the question.

Comment: *"I am aware of that."* but the OP would not have been.